# Estimate of the crowd head count in static image (openCV)

Tags: opencv, counting, haar-classifier

We are trying to count the number of people in a static image, this number may be as large as 100-150. I did some research and found some ways to do this, but we are not sure which one will work the best.So my question is this, will haartraining give us good results? 
If you have more ideas please share with me.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends on how your haartraining goes. Are you wanting to train a classifier specifically to detect faces, and then detect the # of faces in the image and count them up? It's possible that your model will do one or more of these things: a. Count things that are not faces as faces b. Count single faces multiple times. If you can get strong training sets for both positive and negative images, it could definitely be worth a shot as far as ballparking a number. I wouldn't expect it to be exact though.

Comment: Thankyou, yes we are aiming just for an estimate currently. The problem is face may not be pointed towards camera at all times and some may be looking in direct opposite direction